# 0.0 showing up as double when return type is decimal

Tags: c#, .net, types, type-conversion

I came across [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net) and it is very helpful to understand the difference between decimal and double but it does not address my question.

Why does 0.0 default to a double?

[image: 0.0 showing up as double when return type is decimal]

Comment: `0.0m` is decimal. `0.0` is double by default because that's how they wrote the compiler. If you want help with your code, show us the code, not a screenshot of an error message.

Comment: That fixed it! I appreciate the explanation!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Comment: @xxbbcc, I already added that link in my question. As was said, it is very helpful but did not address my question.

Comment: Note that decimal is rarely used compared to double. Most languages don't have a decimal type, and most libraries use double. double is also faster and more memory efficient then decimal. Hence it makes sense to default to double.

Comment: @MaxPringle. In general please include actual code in your answer, not a screenshot. It makes it far easier for us to read. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In this case, I was more interested in why 0.0 defaulted to double and not decimal. I was not asking for a code fix. As was said in the question, I could have fixed easily, but was curious in the reason behind the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0.0m` is decimal. `0.0` is `double` by default because that's how they wrote the compiler. `double` is more commonly used, so that's the one you get if you don't specify a type postfix.

What you want is probably `Task.FromResult(0.0m)`.